# Division in ring $Z[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2]$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Let $w=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$,
Find $q,r \in Z[w]$ such that $3+5w=(2-w)q+r$

What's the best way to approach this kind of questions?

Comment: Unless you put conditions on $q,r$ you have the trivial solution $q=0,r=3+5w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further constraints, one could make a case for cheating being the best approach: $q = 0$, and $r = 3+5w$ fulfills the requirements.

But to seriously compute such things, the best approach is probably to compute in $\mathbb{Q}[w]$, which is a field, and then find the $\mathbb{Z}[w]$ solution by approximating the rational coefficients with integers. Here, most likely the intention is to obtain an $r$ that is closer to $0$ than the left hand side, for the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor.

Then you compute the quotient of the two given numbers in $\mathbb{Q}[w]$ by rationalising the denominator,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{3+5w}{2-w} &= \frac{(3+5w)(2-\overline{w})}{(2-w)(2-\overline{w})}\\
&= \frac{6 -5 \lvert w\rvert^2 + 10 w - 3 \overline{w}}{4 + \lvert w\rvert^2 - 2(w + \overline{w})}\\
&= \frac{1 + 10 w - 3(-1-w)}{5 -2(-1)}\\
&= \frac{4+13w}{7},
\end{align}$$

since $\overline{w} = \frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2} = -1-w$ and $\lvert w\rvert^2 = w\overline{w} = 1$.

The closest integers to the coefficients $\frac{4}{7}$ and $\frac{13}{7}$ are $1$ resp. $2$, so the candidate for the $\mathbb{Z}[w]$-quotient $q$ is $q = 1+2w$, and that leads to

$$\begin{align}
r &= 3+5w - (2-w)q\\
&= 3+5w - (2-w)(1+2w)\\
&= 3+5w - (2 + 3w - 2w^2)\\
&= 3+5w - (2+3w +2(w+1))\\
&= 3+5w - (4+5w)\\
&= -1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ q=q_1 + q_2w $ and $\ r=r_1 + r_2w $, then

$\ 3+5w = (2-w)(q_1+q_2w) + (r_1+r_2w) = 2q_1 + q_2w -q_1w - q_2w² + r_1+r_2w $

since $\ w² = (1-2\sqrt{-3}-3)/4 = -(1+w) $, it follows

$\ 3+5w = 2q_1 +q_2w -q_1w + q_2+q_2w + r_1+r_2w $

Gathering terms and equating coefficients, you can express r in terms of q, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, but Daniel's answer is what I was looking for