# Euclidean Algorithm in $\mathbb{Z}[w], w=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}$

Tags: ring-theory, divisibility

We are in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[w], w=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}$.  I am trying to find the gcd of 2-7 and 11.  What I usually do is set up: 11=q(w-7) + r.  I'll find q and r, then write: w-7=q(r)+r_new.  The problem that I'm facing is finding the q in 11=q(w-7)+r.

What I usually do is write out: $\dfrac{11}{w-7} \dfrac{w+7}{w+7}=\dfrac{11w+77}{w^2-49}$, I would separate terms to get: $\dfrac{11w}{w^2-49}+\dfrac{77}{w^2-49}$, then I would round each term down to obtain the closest integer coefficient, then make that my q.  I am having trouble with this $w^2$ term, I'm not sure how to treat it and, thus, how to continue with the algorithm.  Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685078/division-in-ring-z-frac-1-sqrt-32), it's a different ring, but the principle is the same. You need the conjugate, $$\frac{11}{w-7}\cdot \frac{\overline{w}-7}{\overline{w}-7}$$ to get a rational denominator.

Comment: It's been a long time since I actively studied ring theory, but how does using a complex number yield integers? Am I missing something? $w=\frac12+\tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2}i$, doesn't it?

Comment: ahhh, I see... then the rest of my thought process works fine. great. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know that you were asked to use Euclid, but it’s really easier to find gcd directly, as follows, if you know that your ring has Unique Factorization. If you do, I’d split $11$ into its prime factors, namely $11=(2+\sqrt{-7})(2-\sqrt{-7})$, and observe first that $11$ doesn’t divide $w-7=(-13+\sqrt{-7})/2$, and then try to divide each of the prime factors of $11$ into $w-7$ to see which division gives $a+bw$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. You’ll find that one of the two prime factors works, the other doesn’t. For myself, by the way, I find it easier to work with expressions of form $\alpha+\beta\sqrt{-7}$ where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Q$ than with expressions in $w$.